# sails.js remove all members from collection waterline

Tags: node.js, collections, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I want to remove all members that a collection has , but I do not want to pass every member `ID` to `.member()` method .
[waterline documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/remove-from-collection) explain a way to delete specific members like :

```
await User.removeFromCollection(3, 'pets')
.members([99,98]);
```

I want to have sth like :

```
await User.removeFromCollection(3, 'pets')
.members(['*']);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this should be done using `.destroy()` without a criteria.

***Edit (2019-07-10):** Added the empty curlies as per the comment from noobular*

```js
await User.destroy({});                // Removes all records from your User collection

await User.destroy({name:'Bill'};    // Removes all records from your User collection
                                        where the 'name' is 'Bill'
```

**Docs:** [`.destroy()`](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/destroy)

### Update

After you pointed out I misread your question, I came up with this solution. The docs for `.removeFromCollection()` states that passing in an array of parent ID's will remove *all* children in the specified collection, but this does not seem to function as written.

I did however find a working solution for you using `.replaceCollection()`.

```js
await User.replaceCollection(3, 'pets', []);

OR

await User.replaceCollection(3, 'pets').members([]);
```

Passing in an empty array will replace the current array of associations with the empty array, clearing out the current associations.

**Docs:** [`.replaceCollection()`](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/replace-collection)

Comment: I do not want to delete `user` it has many-to-many relation with my `pets` , I just want to delete relation

Comment: @Jafarrezaei Ah, I'm sorry. I misread your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks , actually today I solve this with passing needed members ids , but this is correct answer and accepted .

Comment: As of 7/7/19, you'll get an error with just destroy().  Sails will tell you to provide empty criteria, ie User.destroy({}).